# XCode – change a file in the host application depending on the build target?

Tags: swift, xcode, build-process, xctest

I have an OS X application; let's call it **MyApp**. Inside the MyApp target we have a **Singletons.swift** file, which sets up, e.g., DB access.

I also have a UI test target, **MyAppUITests**. If I'm not mistaken, the UI test target doesn't have internal code access to the host application; the host is built in its own debug mode, then the UI tests are built and run separately.

Is it possible to get the host MyApp to use a Singletons.swift file from the MyAppUITests group *when building for the test runner?*

I could, of course, add an environment variable `RUNNING_UI_TESTS` to the test scheme. Then replace Singletons.swift inside MyApp with a **SingletonsLoader.swift**:

```
#if RUNNING_UI_TESTS
  let Singletons = UITestSingletons()
#else
  let Singletons = AppSingletons()
#endif
```

But that's obviously not ideal. I'd much prefer to include one file if we're building the app itself, and another if we're building the app to be a host for the test target.

Is this possible?